# PYQT5 program attempting to load a python module that will launch a new window -- new window is not appearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a window that is intended to open a module and then launch another window described in the class of that module. The window that first opens is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
import importlib.util

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        button = QPushButton('Load Module', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.load_and_run_module)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')

    def load_and_run_module(self):
        module_path = "secondWindow.py"
        self.run_loaded_module(module_path, self)

    def run_loaded_module(self, module_path, main_window):
        try:
            # Load the module
            spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("loaded_module", module_path)
            loaded_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            spec.loader.exec_module(loaded_module)

            print("Module loaded successfully.")

            # Check if the module has a class named 'secondWindow'
            if hasattr(loaded_module, 'secondWindow'):
                # Instantiate the secondWindow class and show it
                window_instance = loaded_module.secondWindow()
                window_instance.show()
                print("Window shown.")
            else:
                print("Module does not have a class named 'secondWindow.'")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error loading or running module: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The module in a file called secondWindow.py and contains this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
import sys

class secondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Second Window')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        print("DEBUG: running")
        label = QLabel('Load Module', self)
        self.layout.addWidget(label)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = secondWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the first script and click the button, it reports:

```
Module loaded successfully.
DEBUG: running
Window shown.
```

but does not show the new window. Note, that the print statement "DEBUG: running" means it seems to be executing the init function in the second window. Any suggestions for how I can get the second window to appear?

I'm running Python 3.11.3

Comment: `self.window_instance = loaded_module.secondWindow()` etc.